# Can't insert row in google spreadsheets api with vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, spreadsheet

could please anybody tell me what's wrong with my vb.net code?

```
        Dim service As New SpreadsheetsService("MySpreadsheetIntegration-v1")

    ' TODO: Authorize the service object for a specific user (see other sections)
    service.setUserCredentials("xxx@gmail.com", "1234")
    ' Instantiate a SpreadsheetQuery object to retrieve spreadsheets.

    ' Instantiate a SpreadsheetQuery object to retrieve spreadsheets.
    Dim query As New SpreadsheetQuery()

    ' Make a request to the API and get all spreadsheets.
    Dim feed As SpreadsheetFeed = service.Query(query)

    ' TODO: There were no spreadsheets, act accordingly.
    If feed.Entries.Count = 0 Then
    End If

    ' TODO: Choose a spreadsheet more intelligently based on your
    ' app's needs.
    Dim spreadsheet As SpreadsheetEntry = DirectCast(feed.Entries(0), SpreadsheetEntry)
    Console.WriteLine(spreadsheet.Title.Text)

    ' Get the first worksheet of the first spreadsheet.
    ' TODO: Choose a worksheet more intelligently based on your
    ' app's needs.
    Dim wsFeed As WorksheetFeed = spreadsheet.Worksheets
    Dim worksheet As WorksheetEntry = DirectCast(wsFeed.Entries(0), WorksheetEntry)

    ' Define the URL to request the list feed of the worksheet.
    Dim listFeedLink As AtomLink = worksheet.Links.FindService(GDataSpreadsheetsNameTable.ListRel, Nothing)

    ' Fetch the list feed of the worksheet.
    Dim listQuery As New ListQuery(listFeedLink.HRef.ToString())
    Dim listFeed As ListFeed = service.Query(listQuery)

    ' Create a local representation of the new row.
    Dim row As New ListEntry()
        row.Elements.Add(New ListEntry.Custom() With { _
            Key .LocalName = "ldVorname", _
            Key .Value = "Joe" _
        })

    ' Send the new row to the API for insertion.
    service.Insert(listFeed, row)
```

Comment: the error occurs on  
Key .LocalName = "ldVorname",

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks correct. Make sure you have added both Imports.

Imports Google.GData.Client
Imports Google.GData.Spreadsheets

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you did an automatic c# to vb.net conversion. Remove the `Key` syntax in your code like this:

```
   ' Create a local representation of the new row.
    Dim row As New ListEntry()
    row.Elements.Add(New ListEntry.Custom() With { _
        .LocalName = "ldVorname", _
        .Value = "Joe" _
    })
```

However, running this code stil gives a `GDataRequestException` saying We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try reloading your spreadsheet.